# HOW can i extract text from SPAN? Please

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, testautomationfx

I don't want to extract by Xpath, I would like a clearer and cleaner code. thank u my World Brothers

From Xpath, OK!!

```
Assert.assertEquals("Digite um e-mail ou número de telefone",driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"view_container\"]/div/div/div[2]/div/div[1]/div/form/span/section/div/div/div[1]/div/div[2]/div[2]/div")).getText());
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Assert.assertEquals("Digite um e-mail ou número de telefone",driver.findElement(By.xpath(//span[contains(text(),'Digite um e-mail ou')]).getText()));`

Comment: Do not Work: Assert.assertEquals("Digite um e-mail ou número de telefone",driver.findElement(By.xpath("//span[contains(text(),'Digite um e-mail ou')]").getText()));  The message erro on the gettext is: The method get text is undefined for the type by

Comment: your question was about writing clean xpath: //span[contains(text(),'Digite um e-mail ou')]

Comment: Yes!!... Can you helpe- Me?

Comment: getText() is of WebElement method so you need to do something like this

`WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.XPATH(//span[contains(text(),'Digite um e-mail ou')]).getText());
Assert.assertEquals("Digite um e-mail ou número de telefone",element.toString())`

Comment: Let it go, nothing you put is working !! .. It would be interesting for you to try to do it on your machine from the image that I put, but as it is not possible we stay here!.

Comment: This drug only runs via absolute xpath !! ..Assert.assertEquals("Digite um e-mail ou número de telefone",driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"view_container\"]/div/div/div[2]/div/div[1]/div/form/span/section/div/div/div[1]/div/div[2]/div[2]/div")).getText());
    Thread.sleep(2000);
    System.out.println(driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"view_container\"]/div/div/div[2]/div/div[1]/div/form/span/section/div/div/div[1]/div/div[2]/div[2]/div")).getText()); 
       driver.close();
   }

Comment: This is a working sample code (exactly what i posted above)... I have just tested this.. .. Can't help you more`// declaration and instantiation of objects/variables
 System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver","geckodriver.exe");WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();String baseUrl = "http://www.walmart.com";String expectedTitle = "Welcome: Mercury Tours";WebElement actualTitle;driver.get(baseUrl); // get the actual value of the text
actualTitle = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//span[contains(text(),'COVID')]"));
       String txt= actualTitle.getText().toString();
        driver.close()`

Comment: Thank U my brother!!
I got it here, look this!!!                                                                            Assert.assertEquals("Digite um e-mail ou número de telefone",driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("div[jsname='B34EJ']")).getText());

Comment: Little annoying thing!!